# Angular-cli Webpack 3rd part css files

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, angular2-material

I just moved to `angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.2`
There are so many annoying things but the biggest problem which I`m facing is with external **css** files (probably I will have the problem with **js** files too).

In my project is used [Angular2 material](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) and the `menu component` is requiring the `overlay.css`. When I am including it in `index.html`:

```
<link href="vendor/@angular2-material/core/overlay/overlay.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And after `ng serve` or `ng build` the overlay css files are missing in the **dist** folder.

There is as [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/1633) on `angular-cli github`. I did everything exactly how it's mentioned but is still not working.

I crated an `assets` folder and `styles.css` file in

- src
- src/app

and my `angular-cli.json` files look like:

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.2",
    "name": "cli-webstorm"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root":"src",
      "assets":"assets",
      "main": "src/main.ts",
      "tsconfig": "src/tsconfig.json",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": "styles.css",
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.dev.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "addons": [],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "config/protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "config/karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "prefix": "app",
    "sourceDir": "src",
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "lazyRoutePrefix": "+"
  }
}
```

I would like to ask how can I include an library css files(3rd part css) in my project in a way that I can use the benefits of `angular-cli webpack`?

Answer (score 19):

Your answer lies within the new `styles` and `scripts` config settings available in `angular-cli.json`. There are two options to solve css injection:

## External Styles

### Option 1

Just include the path to the css file directly in the `styles` array like so:

//-- angular-cli.json --//

```
{
   //... 
 “apps”: [
   {
   //... 
   “styles”: [
     “styles.css”,
     “../node_modules/@angular2-material/core/overlay/overlay.css”
   ],
   “scripts”: [],

     // ...
    }
   }
 ],
```

### Option 2

You can import `overlay.css` into `src/styles.css` file generated by the cli:

```
/* scr/styles.css */

@import "../node_modules/@angular2-material/core/overlay/overlay.css";
```

If you use Option 2, make sure to remove reference to `overlay.css` illustrated in Option 1.

Note: `angular-cli.json` is a configuration file so you'll need to restart the server when making changes to it.

You can find more `angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.2` [details here](https://medium.com/@jeff.boothe/angular-cli-meets-webpack-7c9b1a1e1e89#.e23wgja8c).

## External Scripts

Similar to injecting external styles, you can inject external scripts by using the `scripts:[]` array in angular-cli.json. Any scripts added here will get loaded to the `window` object. This is particularly handy with plugins that require jQuery to be accessed from the `window` object. More on this [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#global-library-installation).

```
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
],
```

Comment: How about including whole folders? Will this ever be possible with angular-cli ?

Answer (score 2):

If you upgrade to `1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.3` or higher, you can use the `apps[0].styles` property of `angular-cli.json` to list external stylesheets for import.

To upgrade from `1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.2`, run:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.3
```

Note: you may need Node.js 6 to get `angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.3` working if you get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...` errors on running `ng version`. See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1883 for details.

If you generate a new project, your `angular-cli.json` should look something like this (note the `styles` property):

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.3",
    "name": "demo"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": "assets",
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.dev.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "addons": [],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "lazyRoutePrefix": "+"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Angular CLI Wiki Stories page has a ["Thirdparty Installation"](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/Stories#thirdparty-installation) section:

```
ng new my-todo-app
ng install sass
```

---

Also, see the [Global Library Installation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#global-library-installation) section of the ReadMe:

> `npm install bootstrap@next`
>
> Then add the needed script files to `angular-cli.json`'s `apps[0].scripts`:

```
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
  "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
],
```

> Finally add the Bootstrap CSS to the `apps[0].styles` array:

```
"styles": [
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
  "styles.css"
],
```

> Restart `ng serve` if you're running it, and Bootstrap 4 should be working on your app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need to include your css file in index.html instead in your ts files. You can simply do import on your css file like this

```
import "yourcssfile.css"
```

if you wish to use them only in components then you may use `styleUrl`

```
 styleUrls: ['yourfile.css']
```

[angular2 webpack seed with angular2material](https://github.com/blinfo/angular2-webpack-seed)

Comment: I am not using `angular2 webpack`. Please check [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) As much as I can see it will be available in the next release of `angular-cli` [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/1633#issuecomment-240723651)

Comment: even if you are not using angular2 webpack but angular-cli you should be able to do a import on css in your main file which will be available in your whole project. it's the same as it says in that issue having css global.

Comment: Thank you @MrJSingh. This is not the result which I was looking for but with some some changes I make it working. Angular2 material is creating a <div class="md-overlay-container"> which is pushed before the closing `body` tag. This mean that we have to disable the encapsulation of our component `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`. I hope that next version of `angular-cli` will resolve this problems

Comment: I think I had this in my seed. I will update my answer as well. Please accept the answer if it helped it can help others as well 

Answer (score 0):

It Works for me, finally, on

> angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.14

and

> webpack@2.1.0-beta.22

...both install locally with

> npm install --save-dev

The combination of the right Versions was the key to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when i wanted to import PrimeNG from [primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/) But i found a styles.scss in my folder...

```
@import './../your_file_path/your_file_name';
```

Should do the trick